# Regular expression to exlude a specific start string

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression string (see below). What I would like is for it to select all the appropriate patterns but not include patterns starting with MZ

PATTERN - `^[A-Z]{2}\d{7}[A-Z]?[A-Z]?$`

I have read some posts regarding look ahead assertions but I'm affraid they are too complicated for me to understand.

Can anyone help?

Comment: COuld you please post some strings that should match and some that should not match

Comment: be nice to know what flavor of regex too.

Comment: Sure. Matches could be - 
AA1234567
BB1234567A 
CC1234567AA 

Non-matches - 
MZ1234567 
MZ1234567A 
MZ1234567AA 
IAMABIGHAIRYAPETHATDOESNOTFITTHISCRITERIA1

Comment: gotcha, though I've been beaten to it

Comment: I'm not sure which flavour of regex. I'm using a vbscript module in qlikview. If I can find out I will get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with pattern

```
^(?!MZ)[A-Z]{2}\d{7}[A-Z]?[A-Z]?$
```

where `(?!...)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which makes sure that `MZ` is not at the beginning of the string.